# How to display Product in Bugzilla ticket list

Tags: bugzilla

I have several products in my Bugzilla database and when I look at my ticket list there is no column for product.

How do I get a sortable Product column to be displayed?

And How do I make it the site default for all users?

Comment: I actually just found the `change columns` and can add the column, but that looks like it is based on a cookie.  

How can I get it to be persistent from machine to machine as well as the site default?

Comment: What version are you using?  I'll answer below for 3.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit Bugzilla/Constants.pm and change `DEFAULT_COLUMN_LIST` to include `product`.

Comment: That worked great.  Now the default has the columns and order that I require.